# how to catch HTTP activity errors only in tibco bw

Tags: http, try-catch, tibco-business-works

In my `TIBCO` BW project I have one process which has some activities like mapper, http, jms etc and I have caught activity also. But I want to catch all the errors created by HTTP activity not other activity errors .
Please help me on this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two solutions.

1. The first-one consists in catching explicitly the exception from the HTTP activity using an "error" branch
   [image]
   [image]
2. The second-one consists to catch the different exceptions throw by the HTTP activity exceptions (HTTP Client exception, HTTP Server Exception, HTTP Communication Exception)

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Yes we can follow these steps also but while trying for this solution i reached to one more solution that we can use catch all activity and after that in transition we check for the HTTP activity error and then forward accordingly.